# OUT parameter needs INPUT

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am doing a course on SQL on MYSQL workbench. In the course I had an exercise in which I had to take an IN parameter value and save as an OUT parameter value for further use.

I came up with this query:-

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS avg_employee_sal_out;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  avg_employee_sal_out( IN p_emp_no INT, OUT p_avg_sal DECIMAL(10, 2))
BEGIN

    SELECT  
        AVG(s.salary) INTO p_avg_sal
    FROM
        employees e
    JOIN 
        salaries s
            ON  e.emp_no = s.emp_no
    WHERE
        e.emp_no = p_emp_no;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Which was the correct answer but when I run the code, the OUT parameter value 'p_avg_sal' was asking for an input.

[Screenshot of when I run the procedure from user interface]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLvfE.png)

If I run the stored procedure in the interface it was fine if I left the out value blank but when I call the procedure I is showing an error.

[Screenshot when I run the above procedure by command]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKp1h.png)

> Leaving the OUT parameter null didn't work, it shows another error

[here is the error screenshot]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mUtp.png)

> In the course when the lecturer ran the same query by user interface it didn't ask for the input for OUT value.

(Sorry, can't provide screenshot cause the lecture is a video and its screenshot is completely black but it the same as [1] if you remove the lower input slot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it done... At least half of it.

It was asking for input for OUT parameter because of a bug in the workbench. It got half fixed when I changed "IN" and "OUT" to the original "in" and "out".

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  avg_employee_sal_out( in p_emp_no INT, out p_avg_sal DECIMAL(10, 2))
BEGIN

```
SELECT  
    AVG(s.salary) INTO p_avg_sal
FROM
    employees e
JOIN 
    salaries s
        ON  e.emp_no = s.emp_no
WHERE
    e.emp_no = p_emp_no;
```

END $$
DELIMITER ;

By doing this its working correctly by running the procedure on the user interface but to call it you have to use variables.

[After changing "IN" and "OUT" to "in" and "out".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l72Eb.png)

To call it by commands someone told me to do with variables like this:-
[here are the commands.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKnqY.png)

The bug was still there in workbench 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The number of arguments to the procedure needs to match, but those arguments don't necessarily need to have a value:

```
CALL employees.avg_employee_sal_out(11203, NULL)
```